# How to add more than one page for a session file?

Tags: php, session

i have this code .. which send parameters via login.php file to the whole site pages ;
Session.php file is :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ID']))
    header("Location: login.php");


else
{ 
    $UsrID      = $_SESSION['ID'];
    $UsrName    = $_SESSION['Name'];
    $UsrTypID   = $_SESSION['Type'];
    $LocationID = $_SESSION['LocationID'];
    $IsAdmin    = $_SESSION['IsAdmin'];


}


?>
```

my question is : how to add another page named with : AddEditAlbums.php to the same Session.php file in order to use its parameters in the whole site ?
something like `header("Location:AlbumsAddEdit.php");` to the same file?

Comment: $_SESSION is a superglobal and its contents would be present in all files that call session_start() and use the same session_id(). You can add whatever you want to the session and the new stuff will show up in all the other scripts the next time they're invoked.

Comment: You are looking for these `include()` or `require()`

Comment: i tried to add another header("Location:AlbumsAddEdit.php") but it didnt work out , and when i add another require_once to another session file the firefox said : The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: im asking how to add more than header in session.php in order to add AlbumsAddEdit.php

Answer (score 0):

If this is the complete source code
then you are missing

```
session_write_close()
```

and

```
ob_end_flush()
```

at the end of the php script.

Place them and try it out.

---

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ID']))
    header("Location: login.php");


else
{ 
    $UsrID      = $_SESSION['ID'];
    $UsrName    = $_SESSION['Name'];
    $UsrTypID   = $_SESSION['Type'];
    $LocationID = $_SESSION['LocationID'];
    $IsAdmin    = $_SESSION['IsAdmin'];


}

    session_write_close();
    ob_end_flush();



?>
```

Comment: where to add exactly plz ? im new to php

Comment: sorry but i still dont know how to add another header in the file , the code above gave me nothing new !